# Word for someone who creates maps

Tags: word-request

What can we call someone who creates a map based on somebody's exploration?

For instance one person explores and collects data about a place and another one creates a map from that data? Not just a drawing but with information, a database of the explored place.

I know about "cartographer", but they simply draw a map. I need to imply creating a whole database of the explored place. Like if somebody explores an island then there should be information on fauna, flora, soil, water, atmosphere, landscape, minerals, settlements, inhabitants, radiation (if present). And maybe a lot more.

Comment: The endeavor is called a "geological survey" and it is a team effort, so I don't think there's a noun ending in `-er` or `-or` which means "one who produces a geological survey". "geological surveyor?"

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo this covers our planet only?

Comment: Maps aren't just geography/topography by the way. Maps can contain a lot of the information that you've listed, although all of that information would take multiple maps and is usually presented as an atlas. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_map - it's still cartography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The job of the cartographer is drawing the map.  The gathering of information is done by different sorts of specialists.

The physical layout is measured by a *surveyor*.

Information about plants is gathered by a *biologist*, a *botanist*, or a *horticulturist*; information about minerals and soils, by a *geologist*; about people, an *anthropologist*, *sociologist*, or *ethnologist*.

There is, so far as I know, no general word meaning, "person who collects information for eventual depiction on a map", although perhaps the word *[geographer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography)* might be useful in your context.